# MongoDB different documents count

Tags: mongodb

I would like to copy some documents from one collection to another.
I did it by using

```
use library
db.books.find(
    {
        'languages.key':'/l/eng'
    }).forEach(function(book)
    { 
        db.books_eng.insert(book)
    })
```

In the books_eng collection now i have 9918435 documents but when I get english book count:

```
> db.books.find(
     {
         'languages.key':'/l/eng'
     }).count()
```

the query returns 11897620 documents. I asked why?

Comment: Why are you doing `.insert({count:i})`? If you're copying the book documents between collections shouldn't it be `.insert(book)`?

Comment: You could also try checking getLastError() to see if anything was reported back (although the shell should have rendered any such messages to you). You might also try setting a write concern to majority so you know the nodes in the replica set have your inserts.

Comment: @RyanWeir yes, wrong code. But I don't have a problem with copy document. There are no difference what kind of document i put it. I asked why documents count in booth collection are different.